# How to Gammu sendsms php shell_exec windows 7 and xampp?

Tags: php, windows, gammu

I have already installed XAMPP latest version and installed gammu.

In terminal I can send sms or identify my cellphone, but if i try the same command on php shell_exec or exec there is something wrong.

The command:

```
"C:\Program Files\gammu\bin\gammu.exe" --sendsms TEXT 06706177529 -text "halooo"
This works.
```

The command in php:

```
$a = shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\gammu\bin\gammu.exe" --sendsms TEXT 06706177529 -text "halooo"');
```

This write to me:

> Warning: No configuration file found! Warning: No configuration read,
>   using builtin defaults! Error opening device, it doesn't exist.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually my solution wasnt bad. I just had to copy the configuration files of gammu to the php wich hast the code. So the config needs to be in the same folder with the php.